# How to assign a dynamic model to a Repository?

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, interface

I created a repository that takes a `T` type:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Class
{
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
    void Update(T item);
    T FindByID(Guid id);
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
}
```

If I create a repository using MVC that takes a `T` type, can I assign a `dynamic` model to it so that I can get properties and the type in runtime?

Comment: XY problem. Your problem probably is _"I don't know the type to use for T at compile-time"_, so your solution _"I know, I'll use `dynamic`!"_ caused this question, which isn't going to work. Take a step back and explain your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that but you have to follow proper steps.It terms as Generic Repository Pattern
Following is one of the best example to implement the same.

[Generic Repository Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814768/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Generic-Repository-Patte)